# Visual Studio Test Debug Error? (CI-PHP-Unit w/ Xdebug)

Tags: phpunit, visual-studio-code, xdebug

[image]

Getting this error when I try to xdebug anything in VS Code.

I think the error is occurring due to somewhere in `kenjis/ci-phpunit-test` and VS not being able to find the necessary method/file ?

Any ideas?

I've already tried via php.ini and setting `xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0` and no luck.

Perhaps there is a certain way to set this up in VS Code?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've got 'everything' ticked in vscode's breakpoints settings, so it's breaking on exceptions even if they're caught.